# Rotating a vector out of a plane, until it meets some general vector

Tags: geometry, vectors, rotations

I have some vector line, which is in the $x$-$y$ plane, say
$$\vec{a} = t\left(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ M \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right),$$
and some other general vector,
$$\vec{b} = \left(\begin{matrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{matrix}\right)+ s\left(\begin{matrix} d \\ e \\ f \end{matrix}\right).$$

The two vectors are not parallel, and can be considered to extend infinitely. I want to rotate $\vec{a}$ around the y-axis by $\varphi$, until it for some $\varphi$ intersects $\vec{b}$.  I don't care what the values of $t$, or $s$ are.  By applying the rotation to $\vec a$, and then equating that to $\vec b$, you get the equation:
$$t\left(\begin{matrix} \cos \varphi \\ M \\ -\sin \varphi \end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{matrix}\right)+ s\left(\begin{matrix} d \\ e \\ f \end{matrix}\right).$$

By equating components, I can solve this equation.  The solutions are immense though, I've included one at the end of the post to give a flavour.

I was very surprised at the complexity of the answer, given intuitively it feels like such a simple operation.  Hence I wonder if there's a more simple/beautiful way of solving this problem.

Sample solution for $\varphi$:
$$\cos \varphi = \left( \sqrt{(\text{e} \text{a}-\text{d} \text{b})^2 \left(\text{b}^2 \left(\text{d}^2+\text{f}^2\right)-2 \text{e} \text{b} (\text{d} \text{a}+\text{f} \text{c})-M ^2 (\text{f} \text{a}-\text{d} \text{c})^2+\text{e}^2 \left(\text{a}^2+\text{c}^2\right)\right)} + \\M  (\text{f} \text{a}-\text{d} \text{c}) (\text{f} \text{b}-\text{e} \text{c}) \right) / \left( \text{b}^2 \left(\text{d}^2+\text{f}^2\right)-2 \text{e} \text{b} (\text{d} \text{a}+\text{f} \text{c})+\text{e}^2 \left(\text{a}^2+\text{c}^2\right) \right)$$

Comment: Well, the equation looks good (i havent checked), but most of the time those vectors wont intersect, so?. The vector is too general. Maybe it should be constrained to something. At least, some of the $a,b,c$ figures should be zero, and some of the $d,e,f$ should be 1. No?. Yes?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rotation of line $\vec a$ around the $y$-axis produces a conical surface, whose equation is:

$$
(M-y)^2=M^2(x^2+z^2).
$$

Thus, a rotated copy of $\vec a$ intersects line $\vec b$ if and only if line $\vec b$ intersects the cone, that is if there exists some $s$ such that:
$$
(M-b-se)^2=M^2[(a+sd)^2+(c+sf)^2].
$$
This is a quadratic equation in $s$: if it has solutions, then you can find the point(s) where the rotated $\vec a$ meets $\vec b$. Once you have an intersection point, it is easy to find the corresponding rotation angle, if needed.

Comment: Thanks.  I was also able to find a way of doing it with cross products and dot products.